# wanting to move up from ms access, thinking .net? visual studio?

Tags: python, .net, database, ms-access

So I wrote a project-management program for a small business using Microsoft Access 2007.

Now they've requested lots of additional features (timekeeping, privileged data tiers ...)

I personally use Linux, but the whole office uses Windows.

I'm relatively new to programming but like to teach myself using projects like this.

I'm right on the edge on this -- I can't really tell what the path of least resistance here is: do I stay in access + VBA and teach myself a dying, annoying language -- while struggling against all the limitations of Access? Or do I move to something else?

Python seems simple enough ... Whatever I use, i need to be able to offer a GUI.

screenshot so you can get the jist:
http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/9360/screenshot1fi.jpg

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/7338/screenshotmh.jpg

--
notes:
current access project uses seperate frontend-backend for multiuser sharing over a LAN

cross compatibility with linux is not that important to me, i've been using virtualbox for a while now.

--UPDATE--
my wanderings have convinced me that i should proceed in IronPython -- however -- as I try to install the suite in both XP and 7, and fail ... I wonder if this also is something outdated ... most importantly, iv'e been reading up on it and I LOVE PYTHON 3 -- but i need to offer a GUI for Windows not sure where to start with that (including which IDE to use, etc)

Comment: the path of least resistance is stay with Access + VBA ...There is quite a steep learning curve moving from Access to .NET winforms

Comment: Why the hostility to VBA? Is it just part of the general hostility to VB in general? I'd say stay with Access/VBA and a couple of versions from now you'll likely be able to use .NET in place of VBA. That's just my guess, but I can't see MS continuing to maintain Access exclusively with a legacy programming language.

Comment: hostility to VBA comes from my own experience with it + what others have said. php just made so much more sense to me. i found both vba and asp alot more frustrating than php, which I hear is syntactically similar to C?

Comment: plus, i'd rather learn an open language than an owned one.

Comment: @Tristan Lear: I find VB/VBA and ASP much easier to understand than PHP. It's not something inherent in the languages themselves -- it's all about the experience you bring to the table and your level of familiarity with the conventions. I find PHP documentation baffling, to be honest. It always takes me twice as long to solve a PHP problem than it does a similar problem in VBA. But that's because the PHP coding conventions are not second nature to me.

Comment: I really don't think it's helpful to post your Iron Python question buried in this much broader question. Why not create an entirely new question and refer back to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB and C# are certainly similar to Access, and would be good if you are looking to not move too far away.

Python is brilliant but nothing like Access.  It is simply a programming language that happens to have good db libraries. The GUI libraries look pretty good as well though I have never used them. GUI design will be harder in python than C#/VB. Python is free and may be worth just experimenting with ie. build a GUI,connect to an SQLite database. You would probably get a good indication of the feasibility of using python for your purposes.

Dont stay exclusively with Access.   Access is pretty good for small applications and you can do some stuff really quickly.  On the other hand VBA is brutal and is severely limiting.  Try both C# and python if you can.

Comment: Downvote for the absolutely ridiculous hostility to VBA. VBA is a SUPERSET of regular VB, and the Access version is extremely well-adapated for database purposes.

Comment: Fair enough. Much of my criticism may be related to my inability to effectively navigate the msdn library, and inexperience with VB/VBA. I find the docs for python, java, and non-msdn C# documentation much easier to search. Any info I require is usually found with a quick google search. I have not found this with VBA.

Everytime I personally use VBA I get extremely frustrated, but this certainly didn't warrant the "brutal" designation.

Comment: You don't want generic VBA help when you're programming in Access -- you want database-specific solutions, and Access has its own specific object model and its own specific set of functions/commands. Places to start are http://mvps.org/Access/ the Usenet groups with "access" in the name, and websites like http://UtterAccess.com and http://www.access-programmers.co.uk . You'll find lots of database-specific help with VBA, but honestly, using Access you should start by pointing and clicking to build your UI instead of plunging directly into code. And the HELP files are actually quite good.

Comment: at this point I am torn between python and, i suppose C#. i've been reading dive into python 3 and absolutely love it, but I have no idea how to implement a GUI with it. and from the GUI perspective, it looks like WPF + c# (since im so desperate to get away from VB)

Comment: im starting to rewrite modules in python 3 today ... ultimately i think its going to be python3 + pyQt, plus some lightweight SQL db

Comment: I might suggest looking into using python 2.6x with an eye towards making it as compatible with python3 as possible. I say this because there are still libraries which have not been ported to python3 that you may find useful.  Although from what I gather support for python3 is much more complete than last time I looked, so you may never run into a problem while reaping the benefits of 3.x.  As for a db SQLite is pretty much a standard in the "lightweight" db category.  I've used it in many projects in python,java, and ruby and would recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

In an environment like that, you can't go wrong with VB/C#. Try the various [VS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) editions.

If you want something that will translate to Linux a little more, Python and just about any cross-platform GUI framework(QT, or wxpython) would work.

EDIT:
Then there's the database. I would probably suggest sqlite if you want to learn something cross platform. Sticking in the Microsoft world, there's SQL server compact.

In a business environment like that, a .NET app is probably more maintainable(after you're gone, etc) then anything that's not completely Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

MS Access is a desktop database application. One step up is most likely [SQL Server Compact Edition (SQLCE)](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), which operates as part of your application (as opposed to SQL Server Express or higher, which run as system services). I've used SQLCE with a great deal of success in a few applications, and Microsoft is using it in Visual Studio 2010 for the new Visual C++ IntelliSense cache because it's lightweight and performs great.

Despite what I've read on some sources, SQLCE doesn't cooperate well with the Entity Framework. It *does* however work great with LINQ-to-SQL and the corresponding designer. That said, my personal recommendation is you consider combining the following as your replacement:

- Data: SQL Server Compact Edition
- Data/Code: LINQ-to-SQL
- Programming language: C#
- Application framework: WPF

  - Personal note: WPF does have a learning curve, but it's primarily difficult for people who've worked with other frameworks (MFC, WinForms, etc.) for a long time. Pick up a good reference and you'll be productive in no time, plus you'll be skilled in a technology that people are moving *towards* instead of *away*.

Comment: i am familiar with SQL & SQL Server (mysql, mssql2000) .... i've heard of c# (if it looks anything like php i'll love it, and by looks i mean, does the code look pretty at 4 am when my brain is fried) .. the rest .. "linq" & wpf -- are totally new to me -- any recommendations as where to start

Comment: And, for reports, what is being suggested here?

Answer (score 2):

I would say web app (C#) with SQL Express on the back end - but this is just me

Comment: i tried writing a web app in php a while back, but annoyances like having to write my own drop-down calendar control motivated me toward access

Comment: if you worry is just aboyt controls there are lots of them out there to help you, if you you choose the web app route my prefrence would be ASP.net MVC, C#, SQL Express, Jquery UI/Plugins - http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/

Answer (score 1):

WPF has a pretty steep learning curve, especially coming from Access. WinForms would be a simpler path, but it's still a leap from Access. However, both WPF and WinForms have drag-and-drop form construction, and assuming you learn enough VB.NET to convert the VBA business logic, you're more than halfway there. :)

If you implement your project in WPF, you can make it Silverlight-enabled, but that's a whole 'nother can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

I said this in a comment, but I'll repeat it as an answer:

If you look at the future of Access, it's bright. MS is investing a lot in it. Access 2010 in conjunction with Sharepoint 2010 offers some pretty amazing benefits, and you do it all without any VBA (instead you use the new, powerful macros, which have variables, branching and error trapping). You can do this with client Access and no Sharepoint, or you can publish it to Sharepoint and the app runs in the web browser.

My surmise is that one of two things are going to happen in regard to the programming language in Access in the timeframe of the 2-3 Access versions after 2010:

1. VBA remains supported and all the work goes into macros. Eventually, macros become the preferred method for all programming in Access, with VBA eventually deprecated and finally eliminated. Because by that point macros are so versatile and robust, not programming language will replace VBA.
2. the same scenario, except that .NET is phased in as a replacement for VBA.

I would hope for #2, but it depends entirely on Microsoft's view of what Access is, i.e., primarily and end-user tool with upward extensibility (#1) or both an end-user tool and a versatile development tool with unlimited extensibility (#2).

My point is that you can stay with Access, avoid VBA for now (if you really hate it), and probably end up with a workable, stable app.

However, my reservations about macros are very strong, in that I find them very difficult to maintain because of their standalone nature. VBA code is pretty easy to navigate and understand, because it's compiled and because there's a full-featured IDE. Macros are much more compartmentalized and difficult to trace interrelationships between them and the objects they are used in. Add in the embedded macros added in A2007 and it gets even more complicated. I don't know if the Access team is addressing this or not, but for me it's a real step backward in terms of manageability, particularly if the beefing up of macros ends up causing VBA to be deprecated and then not replaced with a correspondingly powerful programming language with a good IDE.

Last of all, I've said nothing about the database engine, since Access is completely agnostic on this regard, able to use Jet/ACE to start with and then to upsize to the engine of your choice. It's a non-issue, seems to me, since your options are wide open when using Access as your front end.

Comment: i wish they would have phased in .net a few versions ago. everything i've seen thats written in .net is beautiful and fast. 

i didn't know macro's were now favored over vba (i have beta 2010) -- i'll take a look -- right now i have quite a bit of vba code but, and this is one of the reasons im itching to move to something else -- most howto's for stuff i've been looking up were written for .net

Comment: I will say that since we get a 64 bit version of VBA in access 2010, then some real investment has occured in VBA. So, there certainly nothing yet that says a "lid" is being put on VBA.

Comment: @Tristan Lear: I didn't state that macros are favored. I suggested that they might one day be. And the "beauty" of .NET is in the eye of the beholder. For most desktop database applications, it looks to me like using a bulldozer to plant marigolds.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Do you still feel the same way today David? MS lack of investment in this platform has left me demoralized.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your criteria, I would use PyGtk and Glade.  Gtk is well supported on Windows and Linux, and I've gotten more done in less time with Python and GTK, than with any other language/toolkit combination.

If you are willing to rethink doing it on the web, have a look at [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com), which provides a lot of desktop like web controls, and they have a GUI builder.

For the database I would go with Postgresql, or SQLite.  Be aware that SQLite has some severe limitations when it comes to concurrency, which might be a problem depending on your application design, and the number of users.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the clients don't share a database, a .NET WPF/WinForms app w/ an embedded DB sounds like it would work just fine.

You could probably even develop something that works on both Windows PCs and your Linux machine using Mono (you'd be stuck with a subset of WinForms...but for a simple business app, there's really nothing wrong with that).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or something similar? You create a rich GUI using web techniques (HTML, CSS, javascript and or python) and compile that to a desktop application.

The advantage would be that you can develop on Linux, and only do the final testing & deployment on Windows.

That said, writing production software as a beginner is not easy. Especially handling errors can be difficult. Be smart and think about "What can go wrong when the user does this"  all the way, and validate input.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only smallish, internal apps you're working on, take a look at [Visual WebGUI](http://www.visualwebgui.com/) - you get a very VB6-like development environment for web apps.  I would not recommend it for large and/or public apps though.